# Is the function $f(x) = x + (1/x)$ always unbounded for $x > 1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

**PROBLEM**

> Is the function $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$ always unbounded for $x > 1$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

The first derivative is
$$f'(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{x^2}$$
which is positive for $x > 1$.

The second derivative is
$$f''(x) = \frac{2}{x^3}$$
which is positive for $x > 1$.

Thus, the function $f(x) = x + (1/x)$ is increasing and concave up, for $x > 1$.

To see the general trend, I graphed the function using Desmos and got the following image:

[image: Graph of $f(x) = x + (1/x)$]

**QUERY**

> > My problem is that I have trouble seeing whether this result implies that $f$ is unbounded for $x > 1$ *in full generality*?

Sure, I know that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{f(x)} = \infty$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}{f(x)} = \infty,$$
but what about the cases in between?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by the 'cases in between'? $f$ is strictly increasing for $x>1$, so $f$ is bounded above by $f(R) $ on $(1,R)$. You don't need to calculate derivatives to see that.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Since $f(x)$ tends to $\infty$ as $x$ grows, it is unbounded.  What else are you asking?

Comment: @lulu, what if $x$ is bounded?  Does $f(x)$ stay bounded?  In other words, are there cases when $f(x)$ is bounded, despite what Calculus tells us?

Comment: $f(x)$ is continuous except at $x=0$.  So, if you take two finite, positive numbers $0<a<b<\infty$, we have $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.  Hence it is bounded on that finite interval.  There is no contradiction with Calculus here.

Comment: @lulu, you still do not get my point.  Please read my question in the title of this post again.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, and as you can see from the other comments and posted solutions, nobody can sort your question out.  To ask if a function is bounded or unbounded you have to specify a domain.  What, exactly, is the domain you want to specify?

Comment: @lulu, well, isn't $D = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | x > 1\}$ a domain?

Comment: Yes, and $f(x)$ is unbounded on that domain because it takes arbitrarily large values in that region.  Problem solved!

Comment: But then again, what would happen if $x$ is bounded from above?  (The reason for this further clarification is because this question is related to a problem that I am currently working on in elementary number theory.)

Comment: Once again, if you take a finite interval $[a,b]$ with $0<a<b<\infty$ then the function is bounded (as it is continuous and the domain is compact).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I think that the OP's  comment above helped clarify the question.)

A function is bounded or unbounded on some interval (or some set).
When we say that some function is unbounded without specifying the interval (or set), we mean on its domain.
The function you are asking about is unbounded (on its domain).
On any bounded interval with positive lower bound, the function is bounded.
So, on $\left(\frac{3}{29}, 95\right)$ and on $(2,137)$ and on $[6,6.003]$ the function is bounded.
On $(0,5]$ and on $(5,\infty)$ and on $(873,\infty)$ it is unbounded.

Answer (score 3):

Your question has the word "always" in it.  That points to a misconception.  If I had a function $f(x)$ for which $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 3$, I would not ask if $f(x)$ was "always" $3$.    It could be that $f(x)$ is *never* $3$, but only asymptotic to it.

So when we say $f(x)$ is "unbounded" we mean it approaches infinity somewhere, not everywhere (or "always".)  Your function is unbounded on $1<x<\infty$, but at no point in that interval is the value of $f(x)$ actually equal to infinity.

Comment: Nicely put!  +1.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: using $AM-GM$ we get (since $x>1$) we have $$x+\frac{1}{x}\geq 2$$

Comment: What about if $x$ is bounded, @Dr.SonnhardGraubner?

Comment: but the problem states that is given $x>1$

Comment: $x>1$ means $1$ is a lower bound for $x$.  Nowhere did I state that there is or there is not an upper bound for $x$.

Comment: the $\lim_{x\to \infty}x+\frac{1}{x}=+\infty$ since $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$$

Comment: and $$f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$$ is for all $x>1$ monotonoulsy increasing so if we have $$x\le c$$ then the upper bound is $f(c)$

Comment: If $x$ is bounded, $1 < x \leq R$, so
$$\frac{1}{R} \leq \frac{1}{x} < 1,$$
which implies that $f(x) = x + (1/x)$ is bounded.

If $f(x) = x + (1/x)$ is bounded, does it follow that $x$ is bounded?

Comment: since $f(x)$ is for $x>1$ monotonously increasing and unbounded follows that $x$ must bounded

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. Try $x\rightarrow+\infty$.

We obtain:
$$x+\frac{1}{x}=x\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\rightarrow+\infty.$$

Comment: Oh man Michael, you have beaten me!

Comment: What about if $x$ is bounded, @MichaelRozenberg?

Comment: Sonnhard You still can fix your post.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris well if you only look at a compact interval, say $[a,b]$ then $f([a,b])$ is compact and thus bounded (assuming $0\notin [a,b]$ since $f(0)$ is undefined).

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris But you said that $x>1$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, I guess there may just be a misunderstanding.  From my point of view, $x > 1$ is a trivial lower bound for $x$.  But I am not sure if $x$ is bounded, hence my question.

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris By AM-GM $x+\frac{1}{x}\geq2\sqrt{x\cdot\frac{1}{x}}=2$, where the equality occurs for $x=1$ and since $x>1$, we got $x+\frac{1}{x}>2$ and $\inf\limits_{x>1}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)=2$.